# Oracle - how replace utf substring in dec notation with coresponding character

Tags: string, oracle, encoding

i have varchar2 field with values like this: **"abc&#193&#158ef"** and I need to replace all of the **UTF substrings** (e.g. #&123) with its corresponding characters in **DB encoding (cp-1250)**.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I answer myself. First create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decode_string(in_string VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
working_string VARCHAR2(4000) := in_string;
regexp VARCHAR2(20):= '&#[[:digit:]]{3}';
utf_code CHAR(5);
replaced_char CHAR(1);
BEGIN
    LOOP
        utf_code := regexp_substr(working_string, regexp);
        EXIT WHEN utf_code IS NULL;
        replaced_char := CHR(SUBSTR(utf_code, -3, 3));
        working_string := REPLACE(utf_code, replaced_char);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN working_string;
END;
```

Then use this function in clasic update statement:

```
UPDATE foo
SET strfield = decode_string(strfield)
WHERE strfield LIKE '%&#___%';
```

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

you could use a **[NVARCHAR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i45685)** datatype instead of a **VARCHAR2** datatype. Look in the view **`NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`** to determine the **NVARCHAR2** character set (it will always support unicode).

Comment: OK, but i need to replace UTF decimal notation substrings in place instead of creating new field. I need to find all valid UTF substrings in dec notation and replace them with corresponding chracter in cp-1250 (e.g. #&193 -> Á)